# List records from a chosen employee to the ultimate manager

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Given the following Table (In Postgres):

| EmployeeID | EmployeeName | ManagerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | NULL |
| 2 | Jessica | NULL |
| 3 | Gregg | 1 |
| 4 | Joe | 3 |
| 5 | Brandon | NULL |
| 6 | Leslie | 4 |
| 7 | Harry | 6 |
| 8 | Paul | NULL |
| 9 | Frank | 5 |

Starting from **Employee ID 7 (Harry)** - how do I list only the records, bottom-up, in the hierarchy until I get to the ultimate manager (**which should be David**, in this case)? Should I use recursive CTE? If so, how does that query look?

**Expected Output:**

| EmployeeID | EmployeeName | ManagerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | NULL |
| 3 | Gregg | 1 |
| 4 | Joe | 3 |
| 6 | Leslie | 4 |
| 7 | Harry | 6 |

Comment: "*how do I list all records*" - How these records should be made up? Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: @lemon updated withe expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the common table expression, you can recognize:

- the base step, where you select the record relatively to employee no 7
- the recursive step, where you match managers with currently retrieved employees.

The recursion stops when the `INNER JOIN` does not return any more extra record.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM tab WHERE EmployeeID = 7
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT mgr.*
    FROM       cte emp
    INNER JOIN tab mgr
            ON emp.ManagerID = mgr.EmployeeID
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Nuki6nEP7q7sitwR5Gc8r/0).

Comment: awesome! as an aside, which index should be created to allow for more optimization? as this table is representative of a very large dataset.

Comment: You should create an index on (`tab.EmployeeID`, `tab.ManagerID`), because those are the fields where join operations will happen on.